# Javascipt dynamic filter using multiple data types

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have below JSON **data** and  another array is my **filters** using
those **filters** I want to fetch data from this array of objects.

In my **filters** array there are 3 objects and the keys of **objects** are the 
keys of this **data** array.

And in **filters** each key has list of values in the array. Those array **fields** are **values** of this data array.

Using this I want to **filter** and the filter can be dynamic.

Just example in **filters** array 
there is Region key so I will check the list of regions in the below data
then in the next key, there is Item key with some fields then I will filter Item key data under the same region
then in the next key, there is Rep key with some fields then I will filter Rep key data under the same Item

And the **filter** is dynamic fields might be more or less

In given below code I am using it to filter the dropdown type and not range or date type

**dropdown** type in my filter is to filter string fields

**range** type in my filter is to filter numeric string fields

**date** type in my filter is to filter date range fields

```
  var data = [
    {
      "OrderDate": "2019-01-06",
      "Region": "East",
      "Rep": "Jones",
      "Item": "Pencil",
      "Units": 95,
      "Unit Cost": " 1.99 ",
      "Total": " 189.05 ",
      "unique_index": 0
    },
    {
      "OrderDate": "2019-01-23",
      "Region": "Central",
      "Rep": "Kivell",
      "Item": "Binder",
      "Units": 50,
      "Unit Cost": " 19.99 ",
      "Total": " 999.50 ",
      "unique_index": 1
    },
    {
      "OrderDate": "2019-03-15",
      "Region": "West",
      "Rep": "Sorvino",
      "Item": "Pencil",
      "Units": 56,
      "Unit Cost": " 2.99 ",
      "Total": " 167.44 ",
      "unique_index": 4
    },
    {
      "OrderDate": "2019-04-01",
      "Region": "East",
      "Rep": "Jones",
      "Item": "Binder",
      "Units": 60,
      "Unit Cost": " 4.99 ",
      "Total": " 299.40 ",
      "unique_index": 5
    },
    {
      "OrderDate": "2020-05-22",
      "Region": "West",
      "Rep": "Thompson",
      "Item": "Pencil",
      "Units": 32,
      "Unit Cost": " 1.99 ",
      "Total": " 63.68 ",
      "unique_index": 8
    },
    {
      "OrderDate": "2019-06-08",
      "Region": "East",
      "Rep": "Jones",
      "Item": "Binder",
      "Units": 60,
      "Unit Cost": " 8.99 ",
      "Total": " 539.40 ",
      "unique_index": 9
    },
    {
      "OrderDate": "2020-07-12",
      "Region": "East",
      "Rep": "Jones",
      "Item": "Binder",
      "Units": 29,
      "Unit Cost": " 1.99 ",
      "Total": " 57.71 ",
      "unique_index": 11
    },
    {
      "OrderDate": "2020-08-15",
      "Region": "East",
      "Rep": "Jones",
      "Item": "Pencil",
      "Units": 4,
      "Unit Cost": " 4.99 ",
      "Total": " 174.65 ",
      "unique_index": 13
    }
  ];




var filters = [
  {
    "Region": {
      "fields": [
        "East"
      ],
      "type": "dropdown"
    }
  },
  {
    "Item": {
      "fields": [
        "Binder",
        "Pencil"
      ],
      "type": "dropdown"
    }
  },
  {
    "Rep": {
      "fields": [
        "Jones"
      ],
      "type": "dropdown"
    }
  },
  {
    "Units": {
      "from": "1",
      "type": "range",
      "to": "40"
    }
  },
  {
    "OrderDate": {
      "start": "2020-01-01",
      "type": "date",
      "end": "2021-01-01"
    }
  }
];



var filteredData = data.filter(dataItem =>
filters.reduce((pv, cv) => {
var filterKey = Object.keys(cv)[0];
var filterValues = cv[filterKey].fields;
  return pv && filterValues.includes(dataItem[filterKey]);
}, true)
);

console.log(filteredData);
```

excepcted result

```
[
  {
    "OrderDate": "2020-07-12",
    "Region": "East",
    "Rep": "Jones",
    "Item": "Binder",
    "Units": 29,
    "Unit Cost": " 1.99 ",
    "Total": " 57.71 ",
    "unique_index": 11
  },
  {
    "OrderDate": "2020-08-15",
    "Region": "East",
    "Rep": "Jones",
    "Item": "Pencil",
    "Units": 4,
    "Unit Cost": " 4.99 ",
    "Total": " 174.65 ",
    "unique_index": 13
  }
]
```